# Google Geocoding API region parameter

Tags: google-maps, geocoding, google-geocoding-api

In the google geocoding API, what are the regions that are supported by google? region is a parameter passed in the URL which takes a ccTLD value.

Answer (score 2):

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#GeocodingRegionCodes

> This parameter takes a region code, specified as a IANA language region subtag. In most cases, these tags map directly to familiar ccTLD ("top-level domain") two-character values such as "uk" in "co.uk" for example. In some cases, the region tag also supports ISO-3166-1 codes, which sometimes differ from ccTLD values ("GB" for "Great Britain" for example).

http://www.iana.org/assignments/language-subtag-registry